# Maintenance of Fork springs on Marzocchi Bomber Dirt Jumper

Tags: maintenance, repair, fork

I recently took my fork into my mechanic for service because it was making a rattling noise in one of the fork legs. Upon initial assessment he thought it was a broken return spring for the air cartridge. Turns out the fork is primarily spring with a little air on the side. Also turns out that the springs are just worn. Couple questions:

- Am I better off replacing springs or buying a new fork?
- If the springs are that worn, will other parts of the fork be breaking soon?
- Can I replace fork springs myself? I've done an oil change and seals/wipers so far on my own.

Fork is a 2004 Marzocchi Bomber Dirt Jumper 1. Used for dirt jumping and street riding.

Comment: I'm sure the value question is pretty easy to work out around buying new springs or replacing the fork but personally I'd be having a go at reconditioning the forks myself first as that would offer the most enjoyment to me.

Answer (score 2):

Deciding whether or not to replace the fork or to service it, is a question only you can answer. You'll have to calculate how much it will cost to repair vs how much a new fork is. Take into consideration that your fork is a decade old now and that the chances of it breaking will only increase as time goes on. Parts will also be hard to find.

If the springs are worn, you will most likely notice changes in the compression and rebound characteristics of the fork. A worn spring doesn't mean that something else will break.

Yes, you can replace the springs yourself on most forks. Chances are, if you can buy/find a spring, you will be able to replace it. You might need a large socket/wrench for the top cap, but you should be able to do it yourself.